# what should I do when the client request to refresh the valid access token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I am write a refresh access token rest api, now I facing a problem that I did not know what is the right way to handle the refresh invalid access token request. For example, when the access token not expired, the client request for a new access token. should I give a new access token? or give the old token?  or give the token by the expire time, if the expire than greater than 1 hour give the legacy access token, less than 1 hour, give the new access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **issue a new access token**. This improves security and avoids token misuse. Access token rotation (even when they are not expired) is preferred whenever possible.

Further, this fully agree to [OAuth 2.0 rfc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749).

[Refreshing an Access Token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6)

> If valid and authorized, the authorization server issues an access
> token as described in Section 5.1.  If the request failed
> verification or is invalid, the authorization server returns an error
> response as described in Section 5.2.